# Search by city, address, state, mls number

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, search, sails.js

`I have a list of listings in mongodb, so that each listing contains the following fields:

```
{
  "city" : "Yucca Valley",
  "county" : "San Bernardino",
  "fullStreetAddress" : "7496 CHULA VISTA Avenue",
  "state" : "CA",
  "zipCode" : "92284",
  "streetName" : "7496",
  "streetNumber" : "CHULA VISTA",
  "mls" : "41462506"
}
```

I have one search input and I'm trying to write a statement that searches by this columns and returns results. The query split searchQuery by space and search by each word.
For `Yucca` it returns correct result, but it works incorrect for `Yucca Valley` or `Yucca Valley CA`.

Here is my search query:

```
 var searchQuery = req.param('q') ? req.param('q').trim() : null;
      if (searchQuery) {

          var searchQueryArray = searchQuery.split(" ");
          var page = req.param('page') ? req.param('page') : 1;
          var pageData = {};

          var query =  Property.find()

          searchQueryArray.forEach(
              function (queryItem){
                  var orNumeric = [];
                  var orStrings = [];

                  console.log(queryItem);

                  // check, if word contains only numbers, compare it to numeric fields
                  if(/^\d+$/.test(queryItem)){
                      orNumeric.push({streetNumber: {like: "%" + queryItem + "%"}});
                      orNumeric.push({zipCode: {like: "%" + queryItem + "%"}});
                      orNumeric.push({mls: {like: "%" + queryItem + "%"}});
                      query.where({or: orNumeric});
                  } else {
                      orStrings.push({streetName: {like: "%" + queryItem + "%"}});
                      orStrings.push({city: {like: "%" + queryItem + "%"}});
                      orStrings.push({state: {like: "%" + queryItem + "%"}});
                      query.where({or: orStrings})
                  }
              }
          );

          query.where({or: [
              {"fullStreetAddress": {like: "%" + searchQuery + "%"}}
          ]});
```

I guess, this happens because the last `where` overwrites the previous ones. Can anyone suggest how to modify this query that it'll return correct result.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using `.native()` instead of `.query()`.

```
 var searchQueryArray = searchQuery.split(" ");
 var andQuery = [];

 searchQueryArray.forEach(
    function (queryItem) {
       var orNumeric = [];
       var orStrings = [];


                // check, if word contains only numbers, compare it to numeric fields
        if (/^\d+$/.test(queryItem)) {
             orNumeric.push({"streetNumber": {'$regex': ".*" + queryItem + ".*"}});
             orNumeric.push({"zipCode": {'$regex': ".*" + queryItem + ".*"}});
             orNumeric.push({"mls": {'$regex': ".*" + queryItem + ".*"}});
             andQuery.push({"$or": orNumeric})
          } else {
             orStrings.push({"streetName": {'$regex': ".*" + queryItem + ".*"}});
             orStrings.push({"city": {'$regex': ".*" + queryItem + ".*"}});
             orStrings.push({"state": {'$regex': ".*" + queryItem + ".*"}});
             orStrings.push({"fullStreetAddress": {'$regex': ".*" + queryItem + ".*"}});
             andQuery.push({"$or": orStrings})
                }
            }
 );
 Listing.native(function (err, collection) {
     if (err) return res.serverError(err);
     collection.find({"$and": andQuery})
               .sort({"createdAt": -1})
               .toArray(function (err, matchedListings) {
                   if (err){
                      return res.serverError(err);
                   } 
                   else {
                      console.log("Continue code")
                   }
                })
     })
```